# Software Design Website(s)

Tags: oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

What websites (not books) document designs (UML or otherwise) for software applications?

Building architects have many resources available for inspiration and construction. I do not seek resources on constructing software (such as Meyer's [Object-Oriented Software Construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Oriented_Software_Construction)), but rather examples of designs for software components or class diagrams that can be used as a starting point for developing an applcation.

Example applications might include:

- [Game System](http://www.devmaster.net/articles/oo-game-design/)
- Word Processor
- [User Interface](http://docs.hp.com/en/B1171-90148/ch10s05.html)
- Telephony Call Control
- Clinic Scheduling
- Notification System
- Incident Management
- Network Monitoring
- Restaurant Catering
- Dispatching (Taxi, Police)
- [Selling Vacation Packages](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/sad/index.php/System_Overview)

The [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) book is a good start, but a bit too low level.

Comment: I don't recall the name, but an old coworker had a book full of data models for different business domains. All I remember was that it was published by Addison-Wesley around 2003-2004.

Comment: @Ken. Thanks, but I am looking specifically for websites (which, unlike ink and paper, can grow in content over time).

Comment: I know what you mean, but the business domains don't change much over time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Grady Booch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grady_Booch) has a great site for just this thing at 
http://www.handbookofsoftwarearchitecture.com/index.jsp?page=Main

But you do have to register to look at the diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean things like [Microsoft's Patterns and Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

For simple explanations, sample codes and use cases of common software design patterns, you can check out http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns. They are generally aimed at solving common problems and can, in fact, be considered as re-usable architectures in software development.

For information related to domain-specific systems, such as games, there can be other domain-specific problems that have been addressed in different architectures, such as some of the links you have provided. Finding a single source which can list all this information in a unified architecture may not be possible, at best. Generic design patterns, such as those from the Gang of Four, is a better start for this reason, I believe.